# VBA formular1c1

Tags: excel, vba, sum, range, cell

How can I write the formula in the active cell? The active cell already has the formula: `=+sum(i10:i195)-i197`

I want to change this active cell formula to `= sum(i10:I195)-i197+i196`

I have the VBA code:

```vb
WorkSheets(1).range(“i10”).End(xlDown). Select

Selection. FormulaR1C1 = “selectiin -+ selection. Offset(-3,0)
```

But there’s no response. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you explain what it is you are trying to do.  I can't tell from your description above.  Maybe edit the post to add additional information.  Also you should review this post on how to avoid using `.Select` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Easier to understand your code if you could copy and paste it - guessing you're not leaving spaces in the line or spelling `“selectiin` incorrectly.

Comment: Thx Glenn. My question is not clear. I will improve it next time. 

Thx Darren. I will take care my spelling in next time.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the `ActiveCell`'s formula by using its `.Formula` property. Look in `ActiveCell.Formula` to see what its current formula is. Then, if you want to append something onto it, you would just do

`ActiveCell.Formula = ActiveCell.Formula & "+I196"`

If you want this to be an `Offset` of the `ActiveCell`, you need to use the `Address` property like:

`ActiveCell.Formula = ActiveCell.Formula & "+" & ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 0).Address`

Comment: Thx Toddleson. That is what I want. Thx so much

Comment: @JoeChan If my answer has solved your problem, please click the check mark on my answer